# Custom WP query shows different pages with same content

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have a very simple category template with a custom query:

```
<?php $args = array(
          'post_type'  => 'post',
          'category_name' => 'work',
          'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
          'meta_key'  => 'production_date',
          'order'  => 'DESC',
          'posts_per_page' => '6',
        );
        $mi_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

<?php while ($mi_query->have_posts()) : $mi_query->the_post(); ?>
  // POSTS HERE
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>
```

It seems to work but, when I click "older posts" link, the posts shown are the same.

In other words:

```
http://stage.esterpartegas.com/category/work/
```

shows the same than:

```
http://stage.esterpartegas.com/category/work/page/2/
```

You can try it here:
http://stage.esterpartegas.com/category/work/

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `paged` argument.

Try setting `$args` as

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'work',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'  => 'production_date',
    'order'  => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => '6',
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
);
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the help.